# How to transfer data from parent to child only after clicking the button that is in the child. REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As in the title, I would like to send props.pk from ExpenseItem to ExpenseDelete only when the button in ExpenseDelete is pressed. I tried a couple of things myself but it didn't work quite the way I wanted and didn't look very good.

ExpenseDelete.js

```
import "./ExpenseDelete.css";

const ExpenseDelete = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <button className="delete-button" type="submit">
        Delete
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ExpenseDelete;
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
import ExpesneDate from "./ExpenseDate";
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import ExpenseDelete from "./ExpenseDelete";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {

  return (
    <li>
      <Card className="expense-item">
        <ExpesneDate date={props.date} />
        <div className="expense-item__description">
          <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
        <ExpenseDelete />
      </Card>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Comment: What is `props.pk`? Where is that information held? Is it in state?

Comment: Yes,   const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          date: new Date(item.date),
        }));
        setDetails(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "pull" it specifically but can just give it from the parent to its child when declaring it.

ExpenseDelete.js

```
import "./ExpenseDelete.css";

const ExpenseDelete = (props) => {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert(props.pk);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e=>handleSubmit(e)}>
      <button className="delete-button" type="submit">
        Delete
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ExpenseDelete;
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
import ExpesneDate from "./ExpenseDate";
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import ExpenseDelete from "./ExpenseDelete";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {

  return (
    <li>
      <Card className="expense-item">
        <ExpesneDate date={props.date} />
        <div className="expense-item__description">
          <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
        <ExpenseDelete pk={props.pk} />
      </Card>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Comment: I wanted to do it after pressing the button, because in such a situation they are all broadcast at the beginning, but that's nothing wrong yes?

Comment: Unless it is to be specifically avoided for some other reason, I would say there is nothing wrong with it. The Virtual DOM is pretty good at determining what is needed where and when, and works effectively.

Comment: But you could of course use just like in the parent component `axios.get("localhost:8000") .then((res) => { const data = res.data.map((item) => ({ ...item, date: new Date(item.date), })); setDetails(data); }) .catch((err) => {});`. Then you would save the distribution into each component.